# jQuery does not recognise class name prefixed with "/"

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, hide, show, show-hide

I have the following html code:

```
   <div class="/temp">asdf</div>
   <input type="button" class="hide_message_button" value="Hide">
```

And the jQuery for it is something like this:

```
$('.hide_message_button').click(function(){
   var bool = $('./temp').is(':hidden');
   if(bool){
      $('./temp').show();
      $(this).val('Hide');
   }
   else {
      $('./temp').hide();
      $(this).val('Show');
   }
});
```

Well all I am trying to do is show or hide the div on button click. However, I get the following error:

```
Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: ./temp
```

Works fine when the class name is just "temp". Unfortunately, the class name is prefixed with / and I would not like to change it. How do I resolve the error?

Answer (score 2):

You need to escape the meta-characters.

> To use any of the meta-characters ( such as  !"#$%&'()*+,./:;<=>?@[]^`{|}~ ) as a literal part of a name, it must be escaped with with two backslashes: \\

```
$('.\\/temp').is(':hidden');
```

Answer (score 0):

Escape the slash with double backslash.

Answer (score 0):

to escape special charatcers use \

```
$('.\\/temp').is(':hidden');
```

http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/